# How can I overlap TextViews?

Tags: android, android-view

I've just started an android development course and we had an assignment. I should create a simple birthday card app. That was not a problem until I started looking around and saw this picture.

[image: screenshot]

I know 2 ways to achieve this. First, child TextViews in LinearLayout which might not allow to stack them in that sort of leaning/analog fashion. Second, and possible the simplest way I can think of, is to crop the text part and use it as an ImageView on top of the background.

I'm trying to challenge myself to create those bubbles using the code and I was wondering if somebody could help me do it.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to make a screenshot of the TextView?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recreate the stack of words on the right, you cannot use a LinearLayout. The LinearLayout won't allow you to overlap the TextViews. You'll have to use a RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout. Each TextView should have a background image for the color and speckle design, you'll control how big the background is with TextView's `padding` and `margin` attributes.  Finally you can tilt / rotate each TextView with the `rotate` attribute.

Don't get too ambitious with your early homework assignments, you wouldn't want to get frustrated and lose interest!